# Magento | Which security patch can prevent spam customers to register and How to install it?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need you to help me with Magento issue.

How to prevent spam customers to register which security patch we should install and How to install it?

Comment: You can enable native captcha provided by Magento.

Comment: ok I will did but I need to know which security patches should I install on my magento website?

Answer (score 2):

There is no security patch to prevent customer registration spams.

You should try to use captcha as suggested or block suspicious IPs (with the help of your hosting administrator).